# Calling onAuthStateChanged on every request

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

Is there any built-in caching of `onAuthStateChanged`?
I'm building an app using Next.js and Axios.
I defined this method:

```
import { auth, provider } from "./firebase-client";
import { signInWithPopup, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
export function getCurrentUser() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(
      auth,
      (user) => {
        unsubscribe();
        resolve(user);
      },
      reject
    );
  });
}
```

And I want to pass an authorization header on some requests, so what I did for every route is:

```
export async function get(route) {
  try {
    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
    let response;
    if (currentUser) {
      response = await axios.get(route, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.accessToken}` },
      });
    } else {
      response = await axios.get(route);
    }

    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return { error: error.response.data };
  }
}
```

This calls `onAuthStateChanged` on every request to fill in the header. Is this a bad practice? How do I make it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach looks about right. The Firebase SDK already caches the ID token (that is what `user` is based on) in local storage, so subsequent calls should not take much more time than it takes to decode that token.

Comment: why would the subsequent calls take much more time?

Comment: Whoops... that sentence was missing a *not*!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `onAuthStateChanged` to get the current user synchronously? That doesn't make any sense.  That observer method is only for monitoring changes in the user auth state as they happen, allowing your app to globally and immediately respond to auth changes. It's not for one-time use.

If you want to know at any given moment if the user is signed in, use `auth.currentUser` instead as shown in the [documentation, using the second example and not the first one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

> You can also get the currently signed-in user by using the currentUser property. If a user isn't signed in, currentUser is null:
>
> ```
> import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
>
> const auth = getAuth();
> const user = auth.currentUser;
>
> if (user) {
>   // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
>   // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user
>   // ...
> } else {
>   // No user is signed in.
> }
> ```

Comment: `auth.currentUser` may not yet be initialized yet when the code runs, as restoring the user may require a call to the server to check the token/account status. With `onAuthStateChanged` on the other hand, the SDK waits with calling your callback until it has resolved the ID token for the first time (or failed to do so).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The OP's getter function doesn't require that the user is signed in at all.  It has an alternative case for that - simply make the request with no extra headers.  Implemented like this, I don't see that `onAuthStateChanged` adds any value over just polling currentUser at the time of the request.

Comment: The one exception case is that the function will wait to know if there is a user definitely signed in or signed out instead of moving forward with the assumption that the user is signed out immediately when the page first loads. Anyway, in that case, it's better that the entire call of the function (and any state change that would have led up to that point) should be gated by the result of a **single** global auth state observer rather than attaching a new observer each time the sign-in state needs to be known.

Comment: The `onAuthStateChanged` callback will only get called once the initial resolution of the ID token has been resolved (or rejected), while checking the current user happens right when the code loads. --- This is a *very* common way to get the initial-but-restored state with a promise. So common in fact, that the Flutter SDK initially had a `currentUser()` method that was implemented like this (well, the Flutter variation of it).